# Disable checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have three checkboxes. If one checkbox is enabled I want to disable other two checkboxes. How can I implement it using JQuery and HTML?

I want to implement it in mvc 4.

```
Forenoon @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.FromDateforenoon, new { 
    style = "width:auto;", 
    id = "chkFromDate", 
    @onchange = "CalculatedaysOfLeave();" 
}) 
 Afternoon @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.FromDateafternoon, new { 
     style = "width:auto;", 
     id = "chkAfternoon", 
     @onchange = "CalculatedaysOfLeave();" 
})
FullDay @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.FromDateFullDay, new { 
    style = "width:auto;", 
    id = "chkFullDay", 
    @onchange = "CalculatedaysOfLeave();" 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers.If I want to do it in javascript.How can I implement?

Comment: Mussaib Siddiqui's answer is pure JavaScript.  But you did tag the question with jquery lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  if (document.getElementById('idofcheckBox1').disabled == false) {

        document.getElementById('idofcheckBox2').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('idofcheckBox3').disabled = true;

}
```

By this you can easily achieve this

https://jsfiddle.net/7LnwbyLa/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7LnwbyLa

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery:**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function()
{
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

**Note:** Give proper parent with event and property set